# Using siunitx S column in tabu X column

Tags: siunitx, tabu, s-column-type

After updating my MikTex installation from MiKTex 2.9.4175 to 2.9.6361, embedding the S column in the X column did not work anymore. pdflatex fails with the following error message: "Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (S): 'c' used". Simply replacing the up-to-date array.sty with the older version did not solve the problem and the tabu.sty file is the same in both versions. Anyone any clues towards fixing this problem? I would have to update to 2.9.6361 to use other packages.

The MWE (MiKTex 2.9.4175) is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to 0.7\linewidth {X[0.4,$] X[2.5,c]{S} s}
\text{Parameter} & {Value} & {Unit} \\
a_{1}  & -2.60e-3  & \metre \\  
a_{2}  & 10.0  & 1\per\second  \\    
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```